# Adding Username to devise rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails 4 application using devise. I'm trying to allow users to have a username associated with them.

I've added a username (string) column to the Users table, and had my Application controller look like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    protected
    def configure_permitted_parameters
       devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email) }
    end

end
```

and I've also added a field for the username on the users/sign_up page.

But I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `devise_parameter_sanitizer' for #<Devise::RegistrationsController:0x00000101378a28>
```

So basically my question is why is this error appearing, or how else can I get a user to get a username?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're only permitting the username to be allowed on the sign in method, but I'm assuming when you create a new user, it's on the sign up method. So try this:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
end
```

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters

Comment: I'm doing this in my application_controller and I'm able to register and login (immediately after registration). But I'm not able to login from the login page. I have login / authentication key setup for username, and I do have username and password fields in the database. Any clues? Here is a more detailed version of my issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804971/devise-rails-4-not-able-to-login