# Devise - Rails 4 - Not able to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I just started using Rails 4. I got `devise` setup with custom fields. I'm able to login after I register, but I'm not able to login from the login page. The user registration goes in fine, and I have `username`, `password` etc in the database table.

Can somebody tell me what I'm missing? My User model is very basic.
Here is how it looks like -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :username, :uniqueness => true, :presence => {:message => '- Username cannot be blank'}
  validates :first_name, :presence => { :message => " - Firstname cannot be blank!"}    

  private
    def user_params
        params.require().permit(:first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

I've checked my view and I'm passing the right parameters.

I have the following in my application controller -

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  layout :layout_by_resource

  before_filter :configure_permitted_params, if: :devise_controller?

  def layout_by_resource
    if devise_controller?
        "devise"
    else
        "application"       
    end
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:username, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :email) }
  end

end
```

I checked the database table and I do have `username` and `password` (encrypted_password that is). I have my authentication keys set to `username`.

Not sure what I'm missing here. I have `devise 3.0.0`

Comment: Just a long shot: Do you have `devise_for :users` in your `route.rb`?

Comment: I'm really interested in the solution to this. I have also tried to follow https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address and am trying to update the docs myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your application controller you have permitted params for sign_up, but not for sign_in. So i you change the `configure_permitted_parameters` method to this, it should work:

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:username, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :email) }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using devise confirmable. devise.rb was setup in such a way that it wouldn't let me log in if the account's email wasn't confirmed.
So what worked in my case was adding the following flag in devise.rb
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 999.days

Default value is nil which means devise won't let you login until the user has confirmed their email

In my UI I show a error message bar that has a button to trigger resending of confirmation mail. The error bar stays until the user has confirmed their mail.